# html, css with center div. firefox good, chrome not good

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have 6 buttons,
they looks good in firefox. but they are in a bad alignment in chrome.
Anyone know how to slove this problem?

```css
#test {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <button><img src="http://lorempixel.com/99/99"   width="100" height="100"/></button>
    <button><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" width="100" height="100"/></button>
    <br/>
    <button><img src="http://lorempixel.com/101/101" width="100" height="100"/></button>
    <button><img src="http://lorempixel.com/103/103" width="100" height="100"/></button>
    <br/>
    <button><img src="http://lorempixel.com/98/98"   width="100" height="100"/></button>
    <button><img src="http://lorempixel.com/102/102" width="100" height="100"/></button>
    </div>
```

Comment: ?? what do you mean, looks fine to me.

Comment: Have you noticed the second row with the third row it? 1-2 pix

Comment: if the button smaller, for example: width="50" height="50", the problem will be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last br is the issue in chrome. a quick fix is to add one at the bottom

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/4mL8becz/

**Html**

```
<div id="test">
    <button><img src="" width="100" height="100" /></button>
    <button><img src="" width="100" height="100" /></button>
<br>
    <button><img src="" width="100" height="100" /></button>
    <button><img src="" width="100" height="100" /></button>
<br>
    <button><img src="" width="100" height="100" /></button>
    <button><img src="" width="100" height="100" /></button>
<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the `<br>` is probably messing it up, I would wrap each pair of buttons inside a div instead, solves the problem in chrome for me. See jsfiddle below

```
<div id="test">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <button><img src="http://lorempixel.com/99/99" width="100" height="100"></button>
    <button><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" width="100" height="100"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <button><img src="http://lorempixel.com/101/101" width="100" height="100"></button>
    <button><img src="http://lorempixel.com/103/103" width="100" height="100"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <button><img src="http://lorempixel.com/98/98" width="100" height="100"></button>
    <button><img src="http://lorempixel.com/102/102" width="100" height="100"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

`#test {
    text-align: center;
}`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/toywurdn/)

Answer (score 1):

What about floating the buttons in a container and give them a margin?